# Most programs don't use proxy

Tags: proxy, macos

To get internet in my school I have to use the schools http proxy server. So I configured my network preferences to use the proxy. But nearly no program seems to accept that configuration and use the proxy. In Firefox I can help myself with setting FF itself to a proxy connection. But what do I do with all my other programs? Why don't they use the proxy I already set up?
I set the following proxy configuration:

FTP, Web, Secure Web, Streaming, SOCKS, Gopher are all set to proxy.domain.td with port 8080 and Automatic is not set. The proxy doesn't need a user or password and I didn't set one.

What did I forget to set up?

Comment: You just need set one of the above proxy and all of your traffic will send through that proxy.

Comment: Can you be more specific about other programs that aren't using the proxy? (also FF has an option to use its own specified proxy or the one in System Preferences)

Comment: FF is no big problem, as I said. I guess for example QQ, ICQ, Skype and some games like Full Tilt Poker also don't follow along. Don't remember, though. Don't even have a Mac anymore.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Answer is right here:

> To get internet in my school I have to use the schools http proxy server

If the proxy supports only HTTP, it does only support HTTP.

I don't think you forgot anything. Contact your school's IT if they have different addresses/logins for other protocols. If they don't — file a feature request.

Comment: I changed to "only HTTP" but it didn't change anything.

Comment: +1 talking with IT. I'm sure you're not the only Mac user there, so they've probably seen this issue before. I'm curious what kind of networking administrators would beg this kind of trouble, though.

Comment: @erikb But do the non-working applications also use the HTT protocol?

Comment: Don't know. In both configurations the result is just the same. I will speak to the IT guys here. As far as I understand it there is not much more to configure on my computer.